# Подскажите, как можно считать txt файл в C++ с кодировкой UTF-8 с русским текстом

Tags: c++, текст, utf-8

Есть код, который использует tesseract и записывает его в txt файл UTF-8. В тексте присутствуют русские символы. Как сделать так, чтобы они нормально считывались?
Выводит нечто такое: "Р”Р»СЏ С‡РµРіРѕ РЅСѓР¶РЅР° РѕРїРµСЂР°С†РёСЏ \РњРќР•РљР• РІ СЏР·С‹РєРµ 5Рћ1?"

Я использовал wstring, там текст считывается корректно. setlocale, SetConsoleCP уже пытался использовать.

Comment: Видимо у вас проблема не в чтении, а в выводе.

Comment: У меня и в отладчике показывает так же. Так что не думаю, что проблема в выводе

Comment: как из вопроса можно узнать ОС, выполняемый код, откуда эти данные берутся, куда выводятся, байты как бы нормальные `Для чего нужна операция \МНЕКЕ в языке 5О1?`

Comment: Я обнаружил, что если сделать сборки cmd использует 65001, если использовать SetconsoleCP, но в Visual Studio UTF-8 не подключен. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: @Oopss, OC - windows 10. Данные берутся из txt файла. Они никуда не выводятся пока что

Comment: `Выводит нечто такое: `  -куда выводит

Comment: @Oopss Я имел ввиду, что так отображается в отладке. Так отображается в переменной. Я нашел решение, которое позволяет выводить в консоль так как нужно, но именно отладчик VS отображает так, как я показал.

Comment: Отладчик VS предполагает, что в `std::string` данные хранятся в системной кодировке, которая скорее всего windows-1251, а не в UTF-8. Если очень хочется посмотреть что там, можно в Watch добавить что-то вроде `(char8_t *)myString.c_str()`.